# Recursion in BASH

Tags: linux, bash, function, recursion

My task is create script which lists all subdirs in user's directory and write them in a file.

I created a recursive function which should run through all directories from main and write the names of their subdirs in the file. But the script runs for first folders in my home dirs until reaching the folder without the subfolder. How do I do it correctly?

```
#!/bin/bash
touch "/home/neo/Desktop/exercise1/backup.txt"
writeFile="/home/neo/Desktop/exercise1/backup.txt"
baseDir="/home/neo"

print(){
    echo $1
    cd $1
    echo "============">>$writeFile
    pwd>>$writeFile
    echo "============">>$writeFile
    ls>>$writeFile
    for f in $("ls -R")
    do
        if [ -d "$f" ]
        then
            print $1"/"$f
        fi
    done
}

print $baseDir
```

Comment: This could be a lot easier with the help of [find (1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1))

Comment: Use the `globstar` option instead: `for d in **/*/; do echo "$f"; done`

Comment: Simply do `shopt -s globstar; cd; printf "%s\n" **/`. No recursive function needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get all folders within a path you can simply do:

```
find /home/neo -type d > /home/neo/Desktop/exercise1/backup.txt
```

done

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
fun(){
    [[ -d $1 ]] && cd $1
    echo $PWD
    d=$(echo *)
    [[ -d $d ]] && cd $d || return
    fun
}
```